# Problem with selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping the company names as well as the company leads from LinkedIn Sales Navigator, While I get the names of companies in my output, I fail to get the company leads ie. Names of People from the navigator.
Here's the code for the same.

```
# some code
lead_links = []
        leads_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis')
        for lead in leads_button:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(lead.click()))
            #lead.click()
            leads = soup.find_all("div", attrs={
                'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__title.artdeco-entity-lockup__title--alt-link.ember-view'})
            for lead_person in leads:
                lead_links.append(lead_person.a["href"])
# some code
```

what I am trying to do here is that I have created an empty lead links(which basically stores the person's url which could later be used for scraping other information) and I am trying to click the lead buttons. So upon clicking a lead, A tab opens thereby making the rest of the webpage a bit unreadable. and then from the page I click the lead which then changes the url.This is then stored to the lead_links list.

And I get this error. This is the complete stacktrace

```
File "webscrape.py", line 162, in <module>
    linkedin_scraper()
  File "webscrape.py", line 113, in linkedin_scraper
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(lead.click()))
  File "F:\technophile\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "F:\technophile\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "F:\technophile\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\technophile\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-anonymize="person-name" class="button--unstyled t-16 font-weight-600
nowrap-ellipsis" data-control-name="view_lead_panel_via_card_name" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (153, 110). Other element would receive the click: <div id="ember71
7" class="account-sticky-header__lockup artdeco-entity-lockup artdeco-entity-lockup--size-3 ember-view">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

While I have tried using other options with EC such as `EC.presence_of_all_elements located` , `EC.visiblity_of_all_elements_located` but none of them worked. And I am stuck on this issue since a really long time.
Please help me understand how I can solve this error. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(lead.click()))
```

Try using

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of(lead))
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lead)
```

**UPD**
To close the grayed screen in order to click on the next `lead` element try clicking on some element with actions.

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//title[contains(text(),"LinkedIn")]')
actions.move_to_element(title).click().perform()
```

The entire code block will be something like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//title[contains(text(),"LinkedIn")]')
lead_links = []
        leads_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis')
        for lead in leads_button:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of(lead))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lead)
            leads = soup.find_all("div", attrs={
                'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__title.artdeco-entity-lockup__title--alt-link.ember-view'})
            for lead_person in leads:
                lead_links.append(lead_person.a["href"])
            actions.move_to_element(title).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, it however clicks for a single lead and not all.

Comment: How do I ensure that it clicks all the leads?

Comment: What error occurs there? What happens? Can you share the link so I will be able to see what actually happens there?

Comment: No error as such..but on this url, there are multiple people..your answer is only able to click on the first person..once it is clicked from there i scrape the url of the person and other information.

Comment: OK, but YOUR code intended to iterate over list of elements `leads_button` clicking each one of the `lead`. So, what happens when trying to click on the second `lead`? Stale element exception? Something should occur. I just partially fixed YOUR code. I can't see whe web page and what is actually goes there

Comment: Well, you didn't answer me here, but I see your conversation with cruisepandey. Let me know if updated answer worked

Comment: apologies Prophet. I do not get any exception as such.

Comment: I know. Do the updated answer working better? I understand you have grayed screen by clicking the `lead` button. To close it you can click with actions on some title or icon element. Does this worked?

Comment: Got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//title[contains(text(),"LinkedIn")]"}

Comment: OK, again. I have no idea what page you working on.. Try this instead: `title = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.premium-chooser__minimal-nav')`

Answer (score 1):

First I think this should be a css_selector not class name

Replace this :-

```
leads_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis')
```

with this :

```
leads_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis')
```

also when you `click`, use `ActionsChains`:

```
for lead in leads_button:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    time.sleep(2)
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(lead).click().perform()
    # continue with rest of the code here
```

This should be the **import** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Updated 1 :**

```
lead_links = []
        leads_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis')
        for lead in leads_button:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
            #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(lead.click()))
            #lead.click()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", lead)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lead)
            leads = soup.find_all("div", attrs={
                'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__title.artdeco-entity-lockup__title--alt-link.ember-view'})
            for lead_person in leads:
                lead_links.append(lead_person.a["href"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response cruise, This however is not working..neither does it click the button, nor do I get the url's printed on my terminal :(

Comment: Can you share the URL ? and what exactly you are trying to achieve  ? also what went wrong any error stack trace ?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/sales/company/28158595?_ntb=fEe2TlHLQnGKDDtzLnh4Mw%3D%3D&anchor=account-map this is the url. from here there are people.. I want to scrape the links of people..from there I will scrape their other information.

Comment: I see two options `Sales Navigator Professional` and `Sales Navigator Team`. Is it just for premium customers ?

Comment: Yes, its premium!

Comment: hahaha...you can also check the answer by Prophet.. the code which he gave using that, I am able to get one link, however not all.

Comment: also in this case you can send me the page resource if you would like

Comment: Once you click what happens ? Does it redirect to new page ? if it does is it a new page or in same page ?

Comment: it stays on the same page, the rest of the page is greyed

Comment: When you do it manually, do you have to scroll down to click on second element ?

Comment: Manually I would have to close the page, then click on the next person..till the last person is there on the page.

Comment: @technophile_3 :  I have updated the above code, try it out let me know if you run into issues